# Codeception – can't set it up

Tags: php, testing, codeception

I am trying to set up Codeception according to the quickstart guide (available here https://codeception.com/quickstart) but I am stuck at the second step.

When I copy `php vendor/bin/codecept bootstrap` to the cmd prompt, it returns:

```
if [ -d /proc/cygdrive ]; then
    case $(which php) in
        $(readlink -n /proc/cygdrive)/*)
            # We are in Cygwin using Windows php, so the path must be translated
            dir=$(cygpath -m "$dir");
            ;;
    esac
fi

"${dir}/codecept" "$@"
```

I thought it might have been my php version so I downgraded from 8.0.0. to 7.4.13. but the issue remains. Can someone help me out please? Thanks!